# How to reset the sort event that occurs with a click of a Beufy Table with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, bulma, buefy

I am developing the front end through Vue.js and Buefy.

I am using Buefy's Table to sort by a click event on a specific field. Of course, my tables are sorted by creation order by default. (Backend) What I want to do is a temporary alignment that can be done at the front end like now.

Already this is perfect. However, the current column click events will not return to the default sort order (creation order) unless they are refreshed.

I hope you understand my words. If you need additional code or explanation, please do not hesitate to tell us.

Thanks for reading.

I am waiting for your help.

**component.vue**

```
<b-table :data="movies">
  <template slot-scope="props">
    <b-table-column centered="true" field="title" label="title" sortable>
      <strong>{{props.row.title}}<strong>
    </b-table-column>
    <b-table-column centered="true" field="content" label="content" sortable>
      <strong>{{props.row.content}}<strong>
    </b-table-column>
  <template>
</b-table>
```

Comment: Hi kaycle and welcome to stack overflow. I took a quick look at the source code for that component, and there does not appear to be any way to reset the sort order other than, as you've found, refreshing the props.

Comment: Can you tell me what it means to refresh a sort? Do you mean to use a custom sort rather than the sort provided by Buefy?

Comment: I mean refreshing the properties that are passed to the table component, e.g. `this.movies`. I don't know if the table sorts in place. If so, you'd have to keep a copy of the original array and reset movies to that copy. Otherwise, you might get away with something like `this.movies = [...this.movies]` depending on other aspects of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Using Vue you can create a button to reload the table (explanation below).

```
<button @click="resetSortKey = new Date().toLocaleString()">
  Clear sorting
</button>

<b-table
  :key="resetSortKey"
  <!-- ... -->
</btable>
```

And don't forget to initialize `resetSortKey` in your data.

```
data() {
  return {
    resetSortKey = 0,
    // All your other stuff.
  }
}
```

## Explanation

1. We update the value of `resetSortKey` with a unique value (the date/time) whenever the button is pressed.
2. We set the key on the table so that it reloads whenever the value of `resetSortKey` changes. Whenever the table reloads it will clear the sorting and restore the order to the default.